# dist-upgrade fails on libc6 because "kernel too old"

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, upgrade

I have tried for the past few hours to upgrade ubuntu server 14.04 to 16.04 over SSH. The Server is hosted and I have no physical access to it.

It goes well until it updates libc6 and pops up curl with an error and a single OK button, message: `Kernel version not supported  This version of the GNU libc requires kernel version 3.2 or later.  Older versions might work but are not officially supported. Please consider upgrading your kernel.`

It will not continue. I tried manually installing the new kernel via `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial`, which also fails for the same reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This doesn't answer the question, but it explains why there's no answer.

Problem was that the "virtual host" in this case was a container, it didn't use the kernel that was shipped with the operating system, but on the server hosting the container. I was informed that I would have to upgrade the container through the hosting service, which would have come with additional cost. Ended up getting a true virtual server instead so I have more control.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of solutions:

- Compile a new kernel manually and use it.
- upgrade with smaller steps (15,16)
- install xenial in chroot, and copy the kernel + modules to host
  rootfs

Comment: Interested in 2 and 3.... Does 2 even work, though ? Seems like manual upgrade to 14.10 (or 15.04) doesn't work because they don't support them this long ?? for #3 I wouldn't know how.